# elasticsearch get all keys for matching value

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Hi I am new to elasticsearch ,

How can I get all keys matching my query  from an indexed document?

Example document in elasticsearch:

```
{
 testKey1:"The quick brown fox",
 testKey2:"The quck",
 testKey3:"The",
 testKey4:"fox"
 }
```

If I search the index for "fox" , I need to get:

```
  {
  testKey1:"The quick brown fox",
  testKey4:"fox"
  }
```

Please, advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [Multi Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html). Use _source to select fields to return results.

```
{
  "_source": [
    "testKey1",
    "testKey4"
  ],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "fox",
      "fields": [
        "testKey1",
        "testKey2",
        "testKey3",
        "testKey4"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to return only the matched fields , I dont know in advance which ones are matching ...

Comment: The return always be documents, not Fields.

Comment: the question is for fields ... , let say I have 1000 fields in document with different names , if only 2x fileds matching the query I need only those 2x fileds to be shown in the result ...